# how to get data from fireBase push notifications swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using fcm to generate push notifications.

I got the push notifications working but I don't know how to extract the response in Swift 4.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
```

the result of print is this:

> Received data message: [AnyHashable("vibrate"): 1, AnyHashable("id"):
>   35823004, AnyHashable("message"): testMessage, AnyHashable("autoRun"):
>   false, AnyHashable("from"): 523681638965, AnyHashable("title"): testTitle,
>   AnyHashable("notifyType"): notify, AnyHashable("sound"): 3,
>   AnyHashable("largeIcon"):
>   http://test.png,
>   AnyHashable("ledColor"): #f39c12]

So my question is how do I access the data inside of 'title' and 'message' and others?

Comment: `appData` is just `[AnyHashable : Any]` dictionary, use subscript with a key.

Comment: thanks but can you give me an example for extract a value from it? @user28434

Comment: [Exactly like you would do it with any other dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript).

Comment: I try very hardest way to extract but you're right that's very easy :)) thanks a lot @user28434 *_*

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it like below if you want to get the message:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
 let info = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
 if let message = info["messages"] {
  print(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: This method seems deprecated